# Rewrite rule in .htacess

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, web-crawler

I'm having hard time to figuring out how to tell the crawlers like Facebook, Twitter, etc. to read a specific PHP file instead of the current page.

**Edit** : I am doing an Angular.js website.

The thing I am trying to achieve is this :

When we visit http://www.example.com/#!/display/slug-title/1

I would like to redirect the crawlers to http://www.example.com/api/photos/facebook/1

So far, I am trying to ask the rewrite rule to start at the display but the crawler can't get to the information.

```
# allow social media crawlers to work by redirecting them to a server-rendered static version on the page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule display/^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^/]+)$/g https://www.stockiste.com/api/photos/facebook/$2 [P]
```

I am actually running test with this

```
/^([display])+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^/]+)$/g
```

And the test works if I only pass `display/slug-title/1`.

Is there anyway to include, exclude OR tell the file to start at the beginning ?

Comment: You can't rewrite a URL with `#` because it's client side only and everything after it is not sent to the server.

Comment: I am currently reading that I could use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); or #! to have better results. I am still looking into it.